# how to send Javascript string array to controller and render PartialView

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have this problem.

- I have an array in JavaScript as follows:

  checkedItems={"1000","1001","1002"}
- I need to send this array to C# controller
- When controller finish work with this array, return PartialView
- PartialView will be rendered

I tried everything but nothing works.

This is my Javascript:

```
function getAllCheckedFirsts()
{
    var postIds = {
        data: []
    };

    var i = 0;
    $(":checked[id$='-first']").each(function (){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var words = id.split("-");
        postIds.data.push(words[0]);
        i++;
    });

    $.post("/Home/getInfoAboutChecked", postIds);
}
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult getInfoAboutChecked(string[] data)
{
    List<EntityModel> model = new List<EntityModel>();
    if (data.Length != 0)
    {
        int id = 0;
        WSEntityInfo entity;
        WSPropertyInfo[] fids;
        foreach (var e in data)
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(e);
            entity = WSConnect.getEntityInfo(id);
            fids = WSConnect.getAllFidsAsWSPropertyInfo(id);
            model.Add(new EntityModel(entity, fids));
        }               
    }
    return PartialView("_EntitiesView",model);
}
```

But still data in controller is NULL
What is the problem ? and one more question, where and how can I define place for render in html.
THANKS for HELP

Comment: why are you defining `i` ?

Comment: Did you check what is the value of `postIds` before you post?

Comment: in postIds is Object, which has data: array[1] or 3 or whatever, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this (I'm fairly new to JavaScript), but it just so happens I coded a functional way to do this last night:

```
var opts = "";
$('#myForm input:checked').each(function (i, elem) {
    opts += this.value + ",";
});
var ajaxUrl = myUrl + "&opts=" + opts;
```

In the controller I expect one parameter, `string ops`.  In the controller I split the string on "," to get the individual values.

**UPDATE**

Your post can update the HTML like this:

```
$.post("/Home/getInfoAboutChecked", postIds, function(data) {
  $('#idOfDivWhereResultShouldGo').html(data);
});
```

Comment: but I need send whole array and procees every index of array in controller and return partial view according result, but now I don`t understand what is i and elem

Comment: can you send me your command for sending opts to controller with ajax call ?

Comment: works perfectly but how can I define where will be PartialView included (rendered) ??

Comment: Updated to show how to update a `<div>` with the output of the PartialView.

Comment: do you mean $(something).load(...) ?

Comment: I don`t know what is wrong, because, postIds arrive into the controller, controller return PartialView(_EntitiesView,model);
but this it do nothing, still empty page

Comment: evertytime I try do $.post this part: 
function(data) {$('#idOfDivWhereResultShouldGo').html(data);}
has never been executed,

Comment: Are you getting an HTTP 200 response?  You can tell by using the "F12" tools in Chrome or IE, or by using Firebug, to watch the network traffic.  You might also try putting `alert("Success callback called.");` as the first line in the callback function, above `$('#idOfDivWhereResultShouldGo').html(data);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("/Home/getInfoAboutChecked", JSON.stringify(postIds.data));
```

and you can use `@Url.Action to` render the links so assuming home as controller and the other part as action

```
$.post("@Url.Action("getInfoAboutChecked", "Home")", JSON.stringify(postIds.data));
```

your controller expects an array of strings and what you are sending is an object with a property that is an array of strings
also using [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) you can send a simple object with serializing it but not an array so you have to use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @Url.Action will only be effective in a .cshtml file.  It is a better practice to place JavaScript in a separate .js file since that can be minified and cached by the browser.

Comment: doesn`t work, are you sure with brackets ?
and json2.js I have included.
:(

Comment: can you verify the content/type json is being sent to the server

Comment: @ParvSharma: Unless other-wise specified the default content-type is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`. If you want to send Json and specify the matching content-type use `$.ajax({type: 'POST', url: '/Home/getInfoAboutChecked', content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})`

Comment: @user2080814: Not quite sure how `$.getJSON` would work as your action method is decorated with the `HttpPost` attribute, making a `GET` request invalid.

Comment: this 100% doesn`t work , for example first parameter non exist

Comment: @user2080814: You obviously need to pass the data too,  I merely pointed out that you can't use a `$.post` to send JSON data and need to use `$.ajax` if you want to send JSON **and** specify the content-type to match. This was **not** a copy-paste example! Fill in the blanks please to suit :) See [**jQuery.Ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details.

Comment: so I had to use one string and send it to controller and parse it in controller because this is "Spain Village" for me